# How to call a global arraylist in a different method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, arraylist

I am new to selenium, created Page factory. Here is my scenario:

I have declared a public arraylist(say: List1) in class level which stores value from method1, which works fine when printed in same method. Stored in the same way, arraylist(List2) in same class level which stores value from method2.

Now comparing List1 with List2 in method2, List2 shows blank when printed, so my code getting failed.

Not sure what is correct approach

```
    public class AddNewCase {
        WebDriver driver;

        public List<String> List1 = new ArrayList<>(); // Created from Method1
        public List<String> List2 = new ArrayList<>(); // Created from Method2

        public AddNewCase(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        }

        public void Method1() throws Exception {
            // ***some code***
            syso(List1) //Shows correct data
        }

        public void Method2() throws Exception {
            // ***some code***
            syso(List2) //Shows correct data
        syso(List1) // It shows blank data in this method, so the below if condition fails.
            if (List1.equals(List2)) {
                syso("testcase Pass")
            }
        }
    }
```

If list1 matches list 2, result should show pass. Not sure how to call the global array to a different method. When I call List1 in Method 2, result shows blank.

Comment: can you add more code ? , where are you adding data to your lists?

Comment: I think you need to show how you populate your arraylists

Comment: Do you have lists of String class or you just added that for the question? If you are using a custom class, you need to have an `equals()` method in that class

Comment: @UmeshKumar code to add to list:List<WebElement> allText = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='pnlLeftMenu']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr"));
   int total = allText.size();
   for(int i=3;i<=total;i++){
//    CaselevelSigningCMs =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pnlLeftMenu']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr"+"["+i+"]"+"/td[2]")).getText();
    SigningCMsList.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pnlLeftMenu']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr"+"["+i+"]"+"/td[2]")).getText().trim());
    }

Comment: @ShreyGarg I have updated the list1, list2 in class level as public, but when i printed list1 in method 2, it shows blank which works fine when printed in method 1. so the mismatch. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you change your approach. Doing it in this way will prevent parallel execution and can cause problems, likely what you are seeing.

Instead have `Method1()` and `Method2()` return the `List<String>` and then do the comparison (preferably an Assert from TestNG or JUnit) in the test script itself. Change your page object to something like the below. I removed the `public` `List1` and `List2` and created them inside the appropriate methods, `Method1()` and `Method2()`. Those methods return the lists and then the comparison is done inside the test script. This is a best practice to have the validations in the test script and avoid doing validations inside your page objects.

```
public class AddNewCase {
    WebDriver driver;

    public AddNewCase(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public List<String> Method1() throws Exception {
        List<String> List1; // declared here, added to below
        // ***some code***
        return List1;
    }

    public List<String> Method2() throws Exception {
        List<String> List2; // declared here, added to below
        // ***some code***
        return List2;
    }
}
```

Then inside your test script add an assert. The one below is using [TestNG](https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.8.17/org/testng/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.String)).

```
assertEquals(addNewCase.Method1(), addNewCase.Method2(), "Verify the two lists are the same");
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. There is no issue in the code in creating methods and storing the variables. The problem was in the testscript, In one test, I was calling the Class multiple times where the methods are. I had created multiple objects of Class which was the problem. I deleted the multiple objects and in one object, i called all methods one by one. Everything worked fine.

Thanks all for your valuable feedback, I could learn some more also from the others answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct. However, if the order of execution for your methods is not synchronous then, the list built in other method may have empty list. To confirm this, you can add sysoout for list one in Method2. By adding priority @Test(priority=1) for Method1 and @Test(priority=2) for Method2 may resolve your issue.

Comment: all my methods in one class and running the same in one test.

Answer (score -1):

ArrayList equals method returns true only if both list contains same number of elements in the order otherwise returns false. Sort the both lists before comparing as follows.

```
Collections.sort(list1);
Collections.sort(list2);

if(list1.equals(list2))
   System.out.println("Pass");
else
  System.out.println("Fail");
```

Comment: OP stated that list1 is empty. Sorting the two lists won't affect an empty list or solve this problem.